# AES decryption using user-defined key

Tags: winapi, cryptoapi

Is there way to use user-defined key for AES decrypting using WinCrypt API? From what i understand reading the docs and samples, standart way is to generate random key using Windows cryptographic API, the export this key to a file and use it for decryption.

But i need to allow user to define its own password for encryption/decryption.

Comment: Are you asking if WinCrypt supports PBE (Password-based-encryption)? I ask because you're apparently confusing an AES symmetric key (128,192, or 256bits depending on the algorithm of choice), with a user-provided password (could be anything). Such PBE is typically done with a digest algorithm over an expensive (purposely) number of iterations to translate a user-key into a symmetric algorithm key, and there are standard algorithms to do that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It seems i need PBE, yes. Can i do it with WinCrypt API?

Comment: I've never used WinCrypt to perform PBE, though I would be shocked if they didn't have supported for it to one degree or another. A [*key derivation function*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898) along with the appropriate digest algorithm and chosen-encryption algorithm (in your case AES) should be all that is required. You could always code it yourself, but I'll do some searching to see if there is native support for it in the API (and i assume you'll do the same).

Answer (score 1):

The .NET library provides PasswordDeriveBytes in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace for exactly this purpose.  It looks like CryptDeriveKey is the WinCrypt API equivalent.  Yes, you can let your users choose their own passwords, then let this function chew up many microseconds calculating the actual key bytes for the crypto function.  Your end users will never miss those few microseconds, but a brute force hacker being slowed to trying 1 million passwords per second instead of 1 billion will hate it, and this is as it should be.